# Dynymically generate Array

Tags: excel

Is it possible to dynamically generate Boolean or 1/0 arrays in an excel function by comparing two arrays/ranges and looking for matches without VBA?

i.e.

I have one range of cells with an index, say values 1 through 10 in A1:A10.

then another range, C13:C15  which contains values 3,6,7. Is there a way to compare A1:A10 with C13:C15 to generate the following array with ten elements: {0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0} to be used in a sumproduct function? Then drag this comparing different ranges to the index.

Answer (score 0):

You could use logical_test functions to return an array like that, just depends what logic you want to use to get your 1 or 0

See example below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following array formula returns `{0;0;1;0;0;1;1;0;0;0}` based on your cell ranges:

```
= MMULT((A1:A10=TRANSPOSE(C13:C15))+0,((((C13:C15)=0)+1)>0)+0)
```

This is the same desired result as in your question except that it returns a vertical array instead of a horizontal array. If you want to return a horizontal array, just enclose the entire formula above with `TRANSPOSE`. (i.e. `= TRANSPOSE(<formula shown above>)`)

Note this is an array formula, so you must press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on the keyboard instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing this formula.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=SIGN(COUNTIF(C13:C15,A1:A10))
```

If the numbers only occur once in C13:C15, you don't need the SIGN.

So typically this would be in the context of a SUMPRODUCT as you say

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SIGN(COUNTIF(C13:C15,A1:A10)))
```